# What is the best way to add dynamic fields from JSON response

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have json response in that , I am getting fields array. That field array tells me what should i add like textbox , radio button or check box.

I have developed this in two ways
1. Using xibs and add that xibs in scroll view as a subview in a loop.
2. Using tableview.

Problems with first method:-
1. Not looking good.
2. I am not able to give enough gap between views depend on text .

Problem with second method:-
1. I am not able to access cell of tableview which is not visible currently.
For e.x. I have 3 textview in first section and now I am at second section , at this point I am not able to access textview from first section.

Comment: Do you want to display data dynamically in UItable view cell with varying cell height as per content in JSON?

Comment: why did you access textview from first section  ?

Comment: Make tableview custom cells for each type of field..change the cell based on your json field..so you can easily customize those fields UI.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use UITableView and add each element as a section(so you can give space between 2 cells).
2. Use Xibs and use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to calculate height of each cell, so the height is calculated based on the text.
3. Add each element type and data to an local array so You can control
   all elements data.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: This helped! Thanks :)

Comment: I doing the same , but problem is that I cannt able to access textfields and other controls once cell gone out of vision or not visible .

Comment: What do you want to do with other controls? can you explain?